# MEDIA_ROOT error : _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not tuple

Tags: django

I'm new to Django's framework.
When I use the `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),` command in the settings, I encounter the following error when i trying to upload an image in http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/products/product/add/  (admin mode):

`_getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not tuple`

as i try i found deleting MEDIA_ROOT=... will also erase the error and the images will be placed correctly on the path on media's folder.
I think the reason for using MEDIA_ROOT is to understand the path of the media files to Django, but :

1)why when I use it I will encounter an error

2) why I delete this command, everything goes smoothly?
Thanks

setting.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
```

error screenshot is 
[getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not tuple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HysID.png)

project/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
#url will be here
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

i have just an imagefield in my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Product(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100 , verbose_name="نام جنس",null=True,blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category',on_delete=models.CASCADE , verbose_name="دسته بندی" , null=True ,blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="قیمت" ,null=True,blank=True)
    property=models.ForeignKey('Property',on_delete=models.CASCADE , verbose_name="ویژگی" , null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="توضیحات",null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="media/productimage/")


class Property(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=40 , verbose_name="رنگ",null=True,blank=True)
    made = models.CharField(max_length=40 , verbose_name="ساخت کشور" , null=True,blank=True) #made in country


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100 , verbose_name="دسته بندی" , null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of both the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` variables in your `settings.py` have a trailing comma. The trailing comma turns the value of these variables from a string into a tuple.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),  # This is a tuple
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),  # So is this
```

Removing the trailing comma should resolve the problem.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')  # This is now a string
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')  # So is this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
""" Managing media
"""
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Also, import `os` in the same *settings.py* file if you are getting an error while joining the os path.