# Django-ckeditor upload permission for all users; Add scroll bar; & automatically adjust editor width as per screen size

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

**Issue 1:**

I am using Django-CKEditor and when I am trying to upload any file or image in it then it is showing
   **Alert error:  "Incorrect Server Response",**

And when I checked in the terminal, 
   there it is showing **"GET /admin/login/?next=/ckeditor/upload/ HTTP/1.1"**

I don't know what to do to make this work! Please help me here...

**Issue 2:**

when I am copy-pasting 100 lines of text in the editor it increases its height rather providing any scroll bar in it,
  here is the config code I am using:

```
    CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
    CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

    CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
        'default': {
            'height': '200',
            'width': 1250,
            'toolbar_Basic': [
                ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
            ],
            'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
                {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source']},
                {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
                '/',
                {'name': 'basicstyles',
                 'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
                {'name': 'paragraph',
                 'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Blockquote', '-',
                           'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl']},
                {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
                {'name': 'insert',
                 'items': ['Image', 'Table', 'SpecialChar']},
                '/',
                {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
                {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
                {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize']},
            ],
            'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
            # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
            # 'height': 291,
            # 'width': '100%',
            # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
            # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
            # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
            # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
            'tabSpaces': 4,
            'extraPlugins': ','.join([
                'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
                # your extra plugins here
                'div',
                'autolink',
                'autoembed',
                'embedsemantic',
                'autogrow',
                # 'devtools',
                'widget',
                'lineutils',
                'clipboard',
                'dialog',
                'dialogui',
                'elementspath'
            ]),
        }
    }
```

**Urls.py**

```
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

    class table_name(models.Model):
        update_message = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            db_table = "table_name"
```

**Issue 3:**

How to make the width of the editor to automatically adjust as per screen.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue 1:** try to replace

```
path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

in your urls.py with the following

```
    url(r'^ckeditor/upload/', login_required(ckeditor_views.upload), name='ckeditor_upload'),
    url(r'^ckeditor/browse/', never_cache(login_required(ckeditor_views.browse)), name='ckeditor_browse'),
```

also add the following in your urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from ckeditor_uploader import views as ckeditor_views
```

**Issue 2:** 
**EDIT: you had an extraplugin "autogrow" and wrong height setting.**

step 1: remove "autogrow";

step 2: replace

```
'height': '200',
```

with
`'height':'200px',` or `'height':200,`

**Issue 3:** 
replace

```
'width': 1250,
```

with

```
'width': '100%',
```

and in your html and css, make the `div` containing the ckeditor form to be responsive. 
**Note** please pay special attention to `' '` in your code. I see you commented out lines that have correct settings for width and height.

Comment: Hi @ha-neul, thanks for your answer,
issue -2 Is resolved now,
issue 1 is still pending , as now it is showing "error : HTTP error occurred during file upload (error status: 500)."
and in terminal error is "TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list"

Issue 3: is also pending as it is visible in half of the screen,

Comment: for your new issue 1, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54257181/media-root-error-getfullpathname-path-should-be-string-bytes-or-os-pathlike For issue 3, what is the width of the div that containing ckeditor form? Did you try to change that?